# How to use React Native AsyncStorage with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have made login and logout actions and userReducer. How can I integrate AsyncStorage with Redux? I am using Redux Thunk as a middleware.

I am able to implement login and logout using internal state variable but I am not able to understand how to break it down into action and reducer as well as make use of AsyncStorage for storing `accessToken`.

Original Code:

```
_onLogin = () => {
    auth0.webAuth
      .authorize({
        scope: 'openid profile',
        audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'
      })
      .then(credentials => {
        this.setState({ accessToken: credentials.accessToken });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  _onLogout = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      this.setState({ accessToken: null });
    } else {
      auth0.webAuth
        .clearSession({})
        .then(success => {
          this.setState({ accessToken: null });
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  };
```

loginAction.js:

```
   import { LOGIN_USER } from './types';
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';

var credentials = require('./auth0-credentials');
const auth0 = new Auth0(credentials);

export const loginUser = () => dispatch => {
    auth0.webAuth
    .authorize({
      scope: 'openid profile',
      audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'
    })
    .then(credentials =>
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_USER,
            payload: credentials.accessToken
        })
    )
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

logoutAction.js:

```
       import { LOGOUT_USER } from './types';
import Auth0 from 'react-native-auth0';

var credentials = require('./auth0-credentials');
const auth0 = new Auth0(credentials);

export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {

        auth0.webAuth
          .clearSession({})
          .then(success => 
                dispatch({
                    type: LOGOUT_USER,
                    payload: null
                })
          )
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

userReducer.js:

```
  import { LOGIN_USER, LOGOUT_USER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    accessToken: null
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case LOGIN_USER:

            _storeData = async () => {
                try {
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('accessToken', action.payload);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

            return {
               ...state,
               accessToken:action.payload
            };

        case LOGOUT_USER:

            _removeData = async (accessToken) => {
                try {
                    await AsyncStorage.removeItem(accessToken);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }    

            return {
                ...state,
                accessToken:action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I am new to Redux so I tried converting original code into actions and reducers but I am not sure whether I have implemented AsyncStorage in `userReducer.js` correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conveniently use AsyncStorage alone OR redux to manage authentication state. Depends on which you are comfortable with. I will give you an example of both.

For AsyncStorage:
Assuming you have authentication keys that is valid for 2 weeks only. You can take note when your user logs in and save the time. eg:

```
//LoginScreen
import { onSignIn } from '../actions/auth'; //I will describe the onSignInMethod below
import axios from 'axios'; //lets use axios. You may use fetch too.


export default class LoginScreen extends Component {


    //your code: state, static etc
    loginMethod = () => {
        const url = yourauthUrl;
        const payload = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };
        axios.post(url, payload)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                const dateOfLastLogin = new Date().getTime().toString(); //take note of the time the user logs in.
                AsyncStorage.setItem('dateOfLastLogin', dateOfLastLogin);
            }
        })
        .then(() => { 
            onSignIn() //onSignIn handles your sign in. See below.
            .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AfterSignInPage'));
            })
            .catch(() => { // your callback if onSignIn Fails
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => { //your callback if axios fails
        });
    }

}
```

In `../actions/auth.js`

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const onSignIn = () => AsyncStorage.setItem('auth_key', 'true');
//in LoginScreen we called this to set that a user has successfully logged in
//why is true a string? -- Because Asyncstorage stores only strings

export const onSignOut = () => AsyncStorage.multiRemove(['auth_key', 'dateOfLastLogin']);

//now lets create a method that checks if the user is logged in anytime
export const isSignedIn = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        AsyncStorage.multiGet(['auth_key', 'dateOfLastLogin'])
        .then((res) => {
            const userKey = res[0][1];
            const lastLoginDate = parseInt(res[1][1]);
            const today = new Date().getTime();
            const daysElapsed = Math.round(
                (today - lastLoginDate) / 86400000
                );
            if (userKey !== null && (daysElapsed < 14)) {
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                resolve(false);
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => reject(err));
    });
};
```

now we can `import { isSignedIn } from '../actions/auth';` from any of our components and use it like this:

```
isSignedIn()
    .then((res) => {
        if (res) { 
            // user is properly logged in and the login keys are valid and less than 14 days 
        }
    })
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

If you want to use redux

Handling login in redux

In your `types.js`

```
//types.js
export const LOGGED_IN = 'LOGGED_IN';
```

In your redux actions

```
//loginActions.js
import {
    LOGGED_IN,
} from './types';

export function login() {
    let dateOfLastLogin = null;
    let isLoggedIn = 'false';
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(['auth_key', 'dateOfLastLogin'])
    .then((res) => {
        isLoggedIn = res[0][1];
        dateOfLastLogin = parseInt(res[1][1]);
    }); //note this works asynchronously so, this may not be a good approach
    return {
        type: LOGGED_IN,
        isLoggedIn, 
        dateOfLastLogin
    };
}
```

In your loginReducer

```
//LoginReducer.js
import {
    LOGGED_IN
} from '../actions/types';


const initialState = {
    userIsLoggedIn: false
};

export function loginReducer(state=initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case LOGGED_IN:

            const userKey = action.isLoggedIn;
            const lastLoginDate = action.dateOfLastLogin;
            const today = new Date().getTime();
            const daysElapsed = Math.round(
                (today - lastLoginDate) / 86400000
                );
            let trulyLoggedIn = false;
            if (userKey !== null && (daysElapsed < 14)) {
                trulyLoggedIn = true;
            } else { trulyLoggedIn = false }
            return {
                userIsLoggedIn: trulyLoggedIn
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In your `./reducers/index.js`

```
//reducers index.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { loginReducer } from './LoginReducers';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    loggedIn: loginReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

In your store where you used redux-thunk, applyMiddleWare. Lets call it configureStore.js

```
//configureStore.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

In your App.js

```
//App.js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore'; //where you configured your store
import { YourMainNavigator } from '../src/config/router'; //where your root navigator is

const store = configureStore();
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <YourMainNavigator />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

You should know you no longer need the isSignedIn method in your `auth.js`
Your login method remains the same as outlined above in LoginScreen.

Now you can use redux to check the state of login like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    someFunction() {
        if (this.props.loggedIn) {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loggedIn: state.loggedIn.userIsLoggedIn
    };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

There should be a better way of using redux to manage login - better than what I outlined here. I think you can also use redux to manage your login state without using AsyncStorage. All you need to do is in your loginScreen, if the login functions returns a response.status == 'ok', you can dispatch an action to redux that logs the user in. In the example above, using asyncstorage you might only need to use redux to check if a user is logged in.

Comment: I am getting access token when I implement original code given in question. So as far as I understood you are saying that don't use asyncstorage and redux simultaneously. Only redux or only asyncstorage can solve the problem am I right ?

Comment: I was following this tutorial -> https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow

Comment: You can use asyncstorage alone. You can use asyncstorage with redux. Or you can use only redux. For the access token u get during login, you can use asyncstorage to store that. Including client, expiry and uid also if you receive those too.

Answer (score 6):

To persist redux state I recommend you [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

**Installation:**

```
npm i -S redux-persist
```

**Usage:**

First, configure redux store

```
// configureStore.js

import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native

import rootReducer from './reducers'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

Then, wrap your root component with `PersistGate`

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

// ... normal setup, create store and persistor, import components etc.

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootComponent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to use asyncstorage with redux ? I am trying to implement it using asyncstorage

Comment: I am trying to split my original code into actions and reducer but I am not able to use asyncstorage with it.

Comment: @funjoker The `storage` defaults to ‍‍`AsyncStorage` for `react-native`.

Comment: check my updated loginAction.js and lougoutAction.js

Comment: In logoutAction.js should it be -> `payload: null` or `payload: success.null` I want to set accessToken as null after logout button is clicked

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended that you use an abstraction on top of AsyncStorage instead of AsyncStorage directly for anything more than light usage since it operates globally. Redux-persist is that abstraction that goes on top of AsyncStorage. It provides a better way to store and retrieve more complex data (e.g. redux-persist has persistReducer(), persistStore()).

### React native typescript implementation

#### storage.ts

```js
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";

import exampleReducer from "./example.reducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  example: exampleReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ["example"],
};


// Middleware: Redux Persist Persisted Reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer);

// Middleware: Redux Persist Persister
let persistor = persistStore(store);

export { store, persistor };
```

#### App.tsx

```js
import React from "react";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/es/integration/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import RootNavigator from "./navigation/RootNavigator";
import { store, persistor } from "./store";

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <RootNavigator />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```