# React Native - How to store redux state in asyncstorage

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Actually, i am new to the redux concept. I am working on some login app in this i have to store user info stuff in the redux state. I am using this user info throughout the app. But in mobile apps, if we kill the app and relaunch user info obj should be fetched from the redux state. For that, i want to store this object in async storage using redux. Can anyone please help me

code:

```
    const initialState = {
        userinfo : {}
    }

    const UserInfoReducer = (state =  initialState,action) => {

        switch(action.type){

            case 'SAVE_TOKEN' : 
             return {state, userinfo: action.payload}

            case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN':
              return state
        }
            return state

    }
    export default UserInfoReducer;


  saveTokenMethod = async() => {
       var tokenInfo = {
           token : this.state.username
       } 
       this.props.saveToken(tokenInfo)
    }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        saveToken : (tokenInfo) => dispatch({type : 'SAVE_TOKEN',payload : tokenInfo})
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352094/how-to-use-react-native-asyncstorage-with-redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `redux-persist` to handle persisting state to the device since you are using Redux, it will use `AsyncStorage` as default for storing the state. You could also use `redux-persist-transform-filters` to choose what piece of redux should be persisted and which should not.

[redux-persist](https://github.com/edy/redux-persist-transform-filter)

[redux-persist-transform-filters](https://github.com/edy/redux-persist-transform-filter)

Answer (score 1):

retrieve store data when app start

[follow this post](https://medium.com/@sumitkushwaha/syncing-redux-store-with-asyncstorage-in-react-native-2b8b890b9ca1)

Comment: in this i have to add appstate listener in every component

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
First create a reducerfile Index(like index.js)

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import tokenReducer from ./savetoken.js;

export default combineReducers({
   mytoken:tokenReducer 
})





1) Reducer function(savetoken.js)

   const initialState = {
        userinfo : {}
    }

export default (state = initialState,action) => {

        switch(action.type){

            case 'SAVE_TOKEN' : 
             return {state, userinfo: action.payload}

            case 'RETRIEVE_TOKEN':
              return state
        }
            return state

 }

}

2) Action Function

export const saveTokenMethod = (value) => {

return{
        type:'SAVE_TOKEN',
        payload:value
    }

} 

3) LoginPage (Saving token part)..let take loginpage.js

  import * as actions from '../../../../actions';(Give your action page path here)

Class LoginPage{
   .....

 this.props.saveTokenMethod(token);
 var user_token = this.props.mytoken;
 AsyncStorage.setItem('logintoken',user_token );


}

const mapStateToProps = state => {

return{
   mytoken:state.mytoken
}

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,actions})(LoginPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Convert your redux state 
>   JSON.stringify(obj); and store in
>   AsyncStorage

Comment: i can't do it in asyncstorage reducer